# Python/bluez/dbus delete an LE service

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I set up an LE server on a Raspberry Pi using Python/dbus/bluez sample code from the [Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-for-linux/) It automatically allocates standard services with the following UUIDs: 2A00,2A01,2A05,2B29,2B2A,2B3A,2A50. My application works perfectly well and connects faster if these services are missing (when the server is set up by another method). Is there any way of stopping bluez from allocating these services, or of deleting them?

Comment: Device Name and Appearance seem like they are controllable through BlueZ's D-Bus Advertising API. The rest seem like they are requirements of newer versions on the BLE core spec. Is it only the initial connection that is slower? Or are subsequent connections slower also?

Comment: The Advertising registration puts the name (and not the appearance) into the advert packet, which I do need to do, so I suspect that the name characteristic 2A00 is a separate thing, and as you say, these services are being added as part of a standard specification. I'm connecting from an Android device, and I've had lots of trouble with the Android getting services from its cache instead of reading them on each connection. I want the Android to read the services each time, and all subsequent connections are slower.

Comment: You might be at the level were you would need to reconfigure `bluetoothd`. Either with `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, removing plugins at `bluetoothd` invocation (`bluetoothd -h` for more info), or recompiling `bluetoothd` with certain configurations options disabled. More details at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/README.

Comment: I was afraid of that because the Python Application class self.services does not contain these UUIDs, but only the user-added private characteristics.